# Why LSTM+transformer is not working well?

Tags: python, lstm, transformer-model

I'm trying to use LSTM and transformer to do binary-classification, but it does not improve the performance than normal LSTM model, sometimes it will go even worse. Input shape of training data is (3014, 48, 178), input data is time-series medical data, the following code is for transformer.

```
class TokenAndPositionEmbedding(layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, maxlen, vocab_size, embed_dim):
    super(TokenAndPositionEmbedding, self).__init__()
    self.token_emb = layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embed_dim)
    self.pos_emb = layers.Embedding(input_dim=maxlen, output_dim=embed_dim)

def call(self, x):
    maxlen = tf.shape(x)[-1]
    positions = tf.range(start=0, limit=maxlen, delta=1)
    positions = self.pos_emb(positions)
    x = self.token_emb(x)
    return x + positions


class TransformerBlock(layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim, rate=0.001):
    super(TransformerBlock, self).__init__()
    self.att = layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim)
    self.ffn = Sequential(
        [layers.Dense(ff_dim, activation="relu"),layers.Dense(embed_dim),]
    )
    self.layernorm1 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
    self.layernorm2 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
    self.dropout1 = layers.Dropout(rate)
    self.dropout2 = layers.Dropout(rate)

def call(self, inputs, training):
    attn_output = self.att(inputs, inputs)
    attn_output = self.dropout1(attn_output, training=training)
    out1 = self.layernorm1(inputs + attn_output)
    ffn_output = self.ffn(out1)
    ffn_output = self.dropout2(ffn_output, training=training)
    return self.layernorm2(out1 + ffn_output)

class PositionEmbeddingFixedWeights(layers.Layer):
def __init__(self, sequence_length, output_dim, **kwargs):
    super(PositionEmbeddingFixedWeights, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    position_embedding_matrix = self.get_position_encoding(sequence_length, output_dim)                                         
    self.position_embedding_layer = layers.Embedding(
        input_dim=sequence_length, output_dim=output_dim,
        weights=[position_embedding_matrix],
        trainable=False
    )
     

def get_position_encoding(self, seq_len, d, n=10000):
    P = np.zeros((seq_len, d))
    for k in range(seq_len):
        for i in np.arange(int(d/2)):
            denominator = np.power(n, 2*i/d)
            P[k, 2*i] = np.sin(k/denominator)
            P[k, 2*i+1] = np.cos(k/denominator)
    return P


def call(self, inputs):
    position_indices = tf.range(tf.shape(inputs)[-2])
    embedded_indices = self.position_embedding_layer(position_indices)
    return embedded_indices
```

Model code is

```
model = Sequential([tf.keras.Input(shape=(48,178)),
                BatchNormalization(),
                
                tf.keras.layers.GRU(units = 128,recurrent_dropout=0.5,activation='tanh', dropout=0.5,return_sequences = True,activity_regularizer=regularizers.L2(0.01)),

                TransformerBlock(128, 48, 178),
                tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),

                Dense(60,activation='tanh'),
                Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')])
```

It had troubled me for a long time. I'm trying to use LSTM to dealing with the time-series feature, and transformer to learn the importance between features, but it seems not working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The current problem is the RNN + transformer is not working as i thought to be. I have no idea where it goes wrong.